# Google Play Store stopped unexpectedly Samsung Galaxy II

Tags: google-play-store, samsung

While running the play store I am getting the message:

> The application google play store(process com.android.vending)has stopped unexpectedly. please try again,

Force close is indicated in box below the message. I'm unable to
proceed further. I did try few tricks like clearing the data and cache
in play store, but the problem still persists.

My phone details: Android version 2.3.6, model Samsung Galaxy S II, Android 4G, Model no.SGH-T989., kernel 2.6.35.

Answer (score 0):

you can  try to install an updated version of play store, it resolved my problem once.

here is a tutorial i wrote about play store issues  :

[Solutions for the most major play store Problems](http://coding-labs.com/solutions-for-the-most-major-play-store-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing App data for Google Play Store
`Settings >> Apps >> Google Play Store >> Clear Data`

And uninstall updates
`Settings >> Apps >> Google Play Store >> Uninstall Updates`

Then restart your phone